# How to make Python3.7 points to another Python interpreter

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, python-3.7

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.03 and recently i have installed anaconda on my system. Currently,

```
which python --> /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python   #good
python --version --> Python 3.7.4

which python2 --> /usr/bin/python2                 #good
python2 --version --> Python 2.7.15+
```

which are fine.
But,

```
which python3 --> /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3  #oh no
python3 --version --> Python 3.7.4                  #oh no again

#python3.6.8 has been installed in /usr/bin/python3.6
#python3 needs to point /usr/bin/python3.6
```

which is not fine. Also

```
which python3.7 --> /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3.7  #please no
python3.7 --version --> Python 3.7.4                  

#python3.7 has been installed in /usr/bin/python3.7
#python3.7 needs to point /usr/bin/python3.7 not anaconda's 3.7
```

is not fine.

As you probably understood that when i write `python (some version)`, i want to call interpreter in `/usr/bin` not anaconda's except when i write only `python`, i want to call anaconda's interpreter. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What comes up when you enter `which python3.6`?

Comment: It prints `/usr/bin/python3.6` as i expected.

Comment: Add `alias python3='python3.6'` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 1):

Check the content of your `$PATH` environment variable with `echo $PATH`. Find the `anaconda` `bin` directory in the output and change `$PATH` in your shell profile script (`/etc/bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile` for `bash`) to put it after `/usr/bin`. You will probably need to create symbolic links using `ln -s` in order to keep using `anaconda`'s `python` and `python2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the alias pointed by python3.7

```
echo 'alias python3.7="/usr/bin/python3.7"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It is a way of solving the problem, but it will not fix further name collisions in the future. Making sure that `/usr/bin` precedes anaconda in `$PATH` and using symbolic link is a more permanent solution